# Using python-pptx to add table borders

Tags: python-pptx

How can I add cell borders to a table I made using python-pptx? i found an answer here - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-pptx/UTkdemIZICw but when I try to use that _set_cell_border function in my code and call it from within a itercell() loop for each cell it does not give me a border

```
    for cell in table.iter_cells():
        _set_cell_border(cell)
```